# Windows 10: Change my computer name(s)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

When installing `Windows 10`, I get a default computer name of the form **DESKTOP-N1M453R**.
Until recently, this has been fine, since I only had one computer with a name like this, so it was easy to identify at a glance.

Now, I have 3 Windows 10 machines on my network, all with names similar to **DESKTOP-N1M453R**. I'm bad at memorizing those strings, so I'd like to rename them.

I right click on "This PC", then click "Properties".  I click "Change settings" in the "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings" area. I click "Change" next to "To rename this computer..." I enter a new name and click "OK".

I get an error message `"A general network error occurred."`

[image]

Googling for this situation didn't lead to anything promising. Any ideas why I'm getting this error message and how I can workaround it?

Comment: You might want to check your Windows component store for errors. They could lead to strange behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer provided by Steven Murawski via twitter: https://twitter.com/StevenMurawski/status/848176681823203329

Use `Rename-Computer` at a PowerShell prompt (probably need Admin elevation to do it).

[image]

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked, I'll mark it as answered in 2 days

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is resolved!  If that solution worked for you, it might be wise to remove the "probably" from your answer, dependent upon whether it actually *did* or did *not* require an elevated PowerShell prompt when you utilized it.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Every GUI option gives me an error that isn't useful or tells me "The PC name is invalid'. Thanks @MatthewGroves

Answer (score 1):

Looks like contention for same name with cloned installations, so somehow disconnect networking and change all PC's to unique names following naming rules

Comment: What is your evidence? Your source?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use GUI to rename my host after I deleted my teamed nics on Server 2022 standard. After reboot, I recreated the nic team and all is well.

Hope someone finds this useful

Cheers

Comment: For people that don't know, please explain what nics is, in your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).